# PHP - block operation of the user in the website if session timeout is reached

Tags: php, forms, session-timeout

I'm building a website in which I want a session timeout for inactivity of 2 minutes and if the timeout is reached, the operation in the website must be blocked until the user logs in again. I wrote this code for the session and it's timeout:

```
session_start();

    $log_user = $reg_logout = "";
    $log_user_link = $log_user_link2 = $reg_logout_link = $reg_logout_link2 =  "";

    if(isset($_SESSION['name'])!="") {
        $log_user=$_SESSION['name'];
        $reg_logout="Logout";
        $log_user_link="php/personal.php"; //se sono nella home
        $log_user_link2="personal.php"; //se sono in altre pagine
        $reg_logout_link="php/logout.php"; //se sono nella home
        $reg_logout_link2="logout.php"; //se sono in altre pagine
    } else {
        $log_user="Login";
        $reg_logout="Registrati";
        $log_user_link="php/login.php"; //se sono nella home
        $log_user_link2="login.php"; //se sono in altre pagine
        $reg_logout_link="php/registration.php"; //se sono nella home
        $reg_logout_link2="registration.php"; //se sono in altre pagine
    }


    //Expire the session if user is inactive for 2 minutes or more.
    $expireAfter = 2;

    //Check to see if our "last action" session variable has been set.
    if(isset($_SESSION['last_action'])){

        //Figure out how many seconds have passed since the user was last active.
        $secondsInactive = time() - $_SESSION['last_action'];

        //Convert our minutes into seconds.
        $expireAfterSeconds = $expireAfter * 60;

        //Check to see if they have been inactive for too long.
        if($secondsInactive >= $expireAfterSeconds){
            //User has been inactive for too long. Kill their session.
            session_unset();
            session_destroy();
        }

    }

    //Assign the current timestamp as the user's latest activity
    $_SESSION['last_action'] = time();
```

I have included this code in all the page of my website and it partially worked because after 2 minutes if I try to change page, the logout of the user is forced; but if I'm in a page where is a form to interact with the database (I have to pages with form, one for take a reservation and one to delete it) and I press the submit after 2 minutes, my website interact with the database and after that force the logout. How can I block even the interaction with the database after two minutes?

Answer (score 0):

Use below function to check issession expire or not.

```
function isLoginSessionExpired() {      
$login_session_duration = 10;   
$current_time = time();     
if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin_time']) 
and isset($_SESSION["user_id"])){       
if(((time() - 
$_SESSION['loggedin_time']) > 
$login_session_duration)){          
return true;        
}   
}   
return false; }
```

After use below function to re direct logout

```
session_start(); 
unset($_SESSION["user_id"]); 
unset($_SESSION["user_name"]); $url = 
"index.php"; 
if(isset($_GET["session_expired"])) {   
$url .= "?session_expired=" . 
$_GET["session_expired"]; } 
header("Location:$url");
```

For more [link](https://phppot.com/php/user-login-session-timeout-logout-in-php/)